# Get My Public IP via XirSys STUN Request

Tags: stun

Looking through the XirSys API, I don't see a way to simply get my IP address as it visible from XirSys.

Is that possible to get via the exposed API?

Answer (score 1):

The XirSys STUN servers do exactly that, but it's not something you can request from an HTTP request.  If you're using a middleware server (for security), however, then you can do this in pretty much any language.  See for example: [How to get the client IP address in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php)

Comment: Ok that makes sense. So once I make the initial HTTP request and get back the user/pass for my session, what API can I use to get my public IP in say C# or Java?